# Dynamic Text in iOS Bar Button Item

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I'd like to put dynamic text in a bar button item similar to what the new york times does with their number of comments as seen in the picture below.

Any thoughts on how i'd go about achieving this functionality?

[image]

Comment: what the problem to create UIBarButton item global and always set text. Or make your custom class of UIBarButton Item

Comment: How about make an IBOutlet to the button and set its title?

Comment: Not totally sure why this question has been down voted.  This seems like a legitimate question, and I couldn't find the answer on the internet or stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is the [- initWithCustomView:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView:) method of `UIBarButtonItem`.
Here is the pseudo code, modify it according to your needs:

```
UICustomViewController *customVC = [[UICustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UICustomViewController" bundle:nil];
[customVC loadView];  //load the views, so your views won't be nil
[customVC updateText];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customVC.view];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIButton and assign it to your navigation bar right bar button Item.change the text of button whenever there is an update.I created a sample project with Navigation Controller and a custom button on top of the navigation bar and button to [test](http://makeagif.com/i/_0hXZG) that functionality

```
    //Create a button and assign it as rightbarbutton Item.
self.customButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 40)];
self.customButton.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
 [self.customButton setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.customButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:self.customButton];


//Display some random number on navigation bar button
NSString *randomNumber=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",arc4random_uniform(1000)];
[self.customButton setTitle:randomNumber forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can download the sample project from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8bdab5i4cb7jgr/CustomTextOnButton.zip?dl=0)

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question and doesn't work when you try to add a number in the middle of a UIImage.

Comment: @CodingWithoutComments If you want to make the layout nice, i believe customizing a view from IB and controlling the view via a custom controller is a good idea. Have you tried my answer?